Проблема с парсингом данных используя Html Agility Pack
Совсем новичок c#, написал код для парсинга курса доллара исходя данных некоторых банков. Проблема заключается в том что, теперь при вводе любого сайта и указании xPath к нужным мне элементам, они все время возвращают null. При чем это происходит только в методе webSNB, и какой бы сайт и xPath я туда не вставил, ничего не меняется. Пробовал переписывать метод, менять местами, но если поменять местами courseSNB и coursePSB, SNB возьмет его данные. Совсем запутался уже
namespace Kursach
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlWeb webPSB = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlWeb webSNB= new HtmlWeb();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            courseForex();
            courseCB();
            coursePSB();
            courseSNB();
        }
        string dollarRateBuy = "0";
        string dollarRateSell = "0";

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string dollarRBuy
        {
            get { return dollarRateBuy; }
            set
            {
                dollarRateBuy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(dollarRBuy));
            }
        }

        public string dollarRSell
        {
            get { return dollarRateSell; }
            set
            {
                dollarRateSell = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(dollarRSell));
            }
        }

        void courseForex()
        {
            web.UsingCache = false;
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.profinance.ru/currency_usd.asp");
            
            HtmlNode dollarRateNodeBuy = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]//tr[2]//td//table//tr[2]//td[3]//table[2]//tr//td//table//tr[3]//td//table//tr[4]//td[1]//font[1]//b/text()\r\n");
            if (dollarRateNodeBuy != null)
            {
                dollarRateBuy = dollarRateNodeBuy.InnerText;
                dollarRBuy1.Content = $"{dollarRateNodeBuy.InnerText}";
            }
            else
            {
                dollarRateBuy = "Нет данных";
            }

            HtmlNode dollarRateNodeSell = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]//tr[2]//td//table//tr[2]//td[3]//table[2]//tr//td//table//tr[3]//td//table//tr[4]//td[1]//font[2]//b/text()\r\n");
            if (dollarRateNodeSell != null)
            {
                dollarRateSell = dollarRateNodeSell.InnerText;
                dollarRSell1.Content = $"{dollarRateNodeSell.InnerText}";
            }
            else
            {
                dollarRateSell = "Нет данных";
            }
        }
        void courseCB()
        {
            web.UsingCache = false;
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.profinance.ru/currency_usd.asp");
            HtmlNode dollarRateNodeBuy = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]//tr[2]//td//table//tr[2]//td[3]//table[2]//tr//td//table//tr[3]//td//table//tr[2]//td[1]//b//font\r\n");
            if (dollarRateNodeBuy != null)
            {
                dollarRateBuy = dollarRateNodeBuy.InnerText;
                dollarCBBuy.Content = $"{dollarRateNodeBuy.InnerText}";
            }
            else
            {
                dollarRateBuy = "Нет данных";
            }

            HtmlNode dollarRateNodeSell = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]//tr[2]//td//table//tr[2]//td[3]//table[2]//tr//td//table//tr[3]//td//table//tr[2]//td[2]//b//font\r\n");
            if (dollarRateNodeSell != null)
            {
                dollarRateSell = dollarRateNodeSell.InnerText;
                dollarCBSell.Content = $"{dollarRateNodeSell.InnerText}";
            }
            else
            {
                dollarRateSell = "Нет данных";
            }
        }

        void coursePSB()
        {
            webPSB.UsingCache = false;
            HtmlDocument docPSB = webPSB.Load("https://pskb.com/currency/");
            HtmlNode dollarRateNodeBuy = docPSB.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"offline\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]");
            if (dollarRateNodeBuy != null)
            {
                dollarRateBuy = dollarRateNodeBuy.InnerText;
                dollarPSBBuy.Content = $"{dollarRateNodeBuy.InnerText}";
            }
            else
            {
                dollarRateBuy = "Нет данных";
            }

            HtmlNode dollarRateNodeSell = docPSB.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"offline\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]");
            if (dollarRateNodeSell != null)
            {
                dollarRateSell = dollarRateNodeSell.InnerText;
                dollarPSBSell.Content = $"{dollarRateNodeSell.InnerText}";
            }
            else
            {
                dollarRateSell = "Нет данных";
            }
        }

        void courseSNB()
        {
            webSNB.UsingCache = false;
            HtmlDocument docSNB = webSNB.Load("https://www.sevnb.ru");
            HtmlNode dollarRateNodeBuy = docSNB.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span");
            if (dollarRateNodeBuy != null)
            {
                dollarRateBuy = dollarRateNodeBuy.InnerText;
                dollarSNBBuy.Content = $"{dollarRateNodeBuy.InnerText}";
            }
            else
            {
                dollarRateBuy = "Нет данных";
            }

            HtmlNode dollarRateNodeSell = docSNB.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/span");
            if (dollarRateNodeSell != null)
            {
                dollarRateSell = dollarRateNodeSell.InnerText;
                dollarSNBSell.Content = $"{dollarRateNodeSell.InnerText}";
            }
            else
            {
                dollarRateSell = "Нет данных";
            }
        }

        private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            courseForex();
            courseCB();
            coursePSB();
            courseSNB();
        }
    }
}


А вы исходный HTML страницы смотрели? Не в браузере, а тот что получаете в приложении.


HttpClient (а именно он используется под капотом HtmlWeb) должен быть создан только один раз и существовать все время работы приложения. 2. Данных на сайте может и не быть, не смотрите данные браузером, смотрите то, что вам возвращает сам HtmlWeb, сохраните его в блокнотик и анализируйте. Современные сайты зачастую подгружают данные уже после того, как будет прогружен основной UI, делая ряд дополнительный запросов при помощи JS. 3. Не генерируйте xPath, сами ведь видите какую дичь вам выдало. Вот допустим table[1] - а если будет перед этим table еще table? Ищите ID и классы!


И да, хотите получить курс - ищите официальные источники, а не левые сайты. Официальный финансовый источник России - Центральный Банк (ЦБ). Вот открываете его сайт и берете данные, официальные, свежие данные.

Моя курсовая основана на том чтобы я брал данные с нескольких сайтов, после чего их сравнивал. Поэтому одним сайтом ЦБ я к сожалению не обойдусь. Правильно понимаю что все равно нужно использовать один HtmlWeb? Даже если у меня несколько сайтов?

Я не знаю внутренностей HtmlWeb, не знаю какую обертку там сделали, поэтому ответить точно на данный вопрос не могу. Ну а так, читайте документацию (раздел Instancing).

Правильно понимаю что все равно нужно использовать один HtmlWeb? Даже если у меня несколько сайтов? - правильно. По поводу XPath - https://devhints.io/xpath А ещё лучше найдите API, предоставляющие курсы валют. Их полно. Парсить HTML смысла нет. И да, запросы в сеть должны быть асинхронными, чтобы не замораживать приложение на время запроса.

Вот API ЦБ РФ https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/ Вот сбербанк https://client.sbertech.ru/docs/public/CRT/23.01/CRTX/23.01/documents/developer-guide/index.html (у сайта крифой SSL сертификат) Вот альфабанк https://alfabank.ru/ext-json/0.2/exchange/cash/?offset=0&limit=2&mode=rest, ещё варианты https://dtf.ru/flood/1151637-parsing-kursov-valyut

@aepot Это не кривой сертификат, а последствие санкций. Все банки и гос. структуры уже давно перешли на сертификаты минцифры, которые есть в ру. браузерах, но нет в зарубежных. Документация сбера, установите, будет "не кривой".

@EvgeniyZ да оно понятно, но добавление ГОСТ кузнечиков не запрещает поддерживать классический SSL
